# Calling MySQL Stored Procedure on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, view

I cant get my stored procedure or view to work in retrieving stuff from the database. I don't know if my stored procedure or view works, but I do know the php that isn't dealing with those works. 
Please and thank you!

Below is my View and Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE VIEW viewActRole AS
SELECT `tblMovie`.`MovieName`, `tblActor`.`ActFirstName`, `tblActor`.`ActLastName`,    `tblRole`.`Role` 
FROM `tblRole`, `tblActor`, `tblMovie` 
WHERE `tblRole`.`ActID` = `tblActor`.`ActID` AND `tblRole`.`MovieID`=`tblMovie`.`MovieID`;


DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `lookUpMovie`(IN `actorNameVAR` INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM `viewActRole` WHERE `viewActRole`.`MovieID` = `actorNameVAR`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Below is my php code. I know everything worked before adding the stored procedure.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("BLAH", "BLAH", "BLAH", "BLAH");

$dd = $_POST['displaydropdown'];

// used fixed-width font
echo "<pre>\n";
$sp = "CALL lookUpMovie(".$dd.")";
// Get person likes for
echo "$sp";
$r1 = $mysqli->query($sp);

$r2 = mysql_query("SELECT C.MovieName, B.ActFirstName, B.ActLastName, A.Role 
    FROM tblRole A, tblActor B, tblMovie C WHERE A.ActID = B.ActID AND A.MovieID=C.MovieID AND A.MovieID = '$dd'");
$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2);

echo "Albums of Artist: $result2[0]\n";
$fmt = "%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s \n";
printf($fmt, "Movie Name", "Actor First Name", "Actor Last Name", "Role");

// loop over courses, printing each one
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($r1))
{ 
    printf($fmt,$result[0], $result[1], $result[2], $result[3]);
}

// free result set
mysql_free_result($r1);

echo "</pre>\n";
?>
```

Comment: What actually happens when you call the procedure? do you get an empty return set, an error? And have you tried calling the procedure from mysql client? More info please.

Comment: When I echo $sp, I get "CALL lookUpMovie(1)". 1 is corrected. When echoing $r1, I get nothing.

Comment: You won't be able to echo $r1 because $mysqli->query() returns an object. Give the changes I suggested in my answer a go and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing and matching mysqli object oriented calls with the deprecated mysql_* functions. I'm not sure you can do that.

You are doing:

```
$r1 = $mysqli->query($sp)
```

And then passing that to

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($r1);
```

Looping through your results, you need to do:

```
while ($result = $r1->fetch_array())
{ 
    printf($fmt,$result[0], $result[1], $result[2], $result[3]);
}
```

Comment: When I do that, there is an error where it doesn't appear anything below that. Shown here: http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/2412/46925204.jpg

Comment: Is there an error or is the stored procedure not returning results? Have you run the stored procedure from a mysql client to make sure you are getting the expected results?

Comment: I am using mysqlworkbench, and there are no errors. They were added with no problems. The Select statement used in the view works.

Comment: It is actually for an assignment where we are required to use a stored procedure... The professor didn't teach them very well. I will test the view. And see if that works.

Comment: So, in workbench, if you do 'CALL lookUpMovie(1)' it gives you the results that you expect?

Comment: Looking at your image, your line 'Albums of Artist:' doesn't actually have an artist. Are you sure you are getting connected to your DB?

Comment: It says there is something wrong with `viewActRole`.`MovieID` in the where clause of the procedure... I can't figure it out.

Comment: That would do it. If you look at the definition of your view, you don't have a column called MovieID

Comment: I got it to work in mysqlworkbench. I needed to add tblMovie in the from clause of the stored procedure. But not I can't get it to work in the php code.

Comment: I'd put some error checking in there. Like I said a minute ago, one of the lines where you use $r2 to get an actor's name doesn't have a value. You maybe getting errors that will help but you aren't checking for them.

Comment: This is the line giving me trouble. $r1= $mysqli->query($sp);

Comment: Ok, right after you do `new mysqli()`check for errors `if(mysqli_connect_errno()){echo mysqli_connect_errorno()}` to make sure no issues connecting. Then, check to see if `$r1 === false`. If there is an error with the query, `$mysqli->query()` will return false.