# Call MS SQL Stored Procedure from Laravel PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures, mssql-jdbc

I want to call MS SQL Stored Procedure from PHP code of .Net is shown in screenshot I want to call same stored procedure in PHP

[image: call for store procedure in .Net]

I didn't do something like this before.

Here is what I have done on Laravel:

```
public function test(){
$user =DB::select(DB::raw(
    "exec export.spGetConnection @Token = :token, ,@ReturnJSON = :json",
    [
        ':token' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        ':json' => @ReturnJSONOUTPUT
    ])
);
    var_dump($user);
}
```

But getting error

[image]

********* THIS CODE IN CORE PHP WORKS FOR ME *****************

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$tsql_callSP = "{call export.spGetConnection( ?, ?)}";  

$Token = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
$employeeId = 4;  
$ReturnJSON = "";  
$params = array(   
             array($Token, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
             array(&$ReturnJSON, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)  
           );  
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code? What's the question?

Comment: Have you looked on the internet? The tutorial you seek is easy to find. Here are about 800,000 of them. https://www.google.com/search?q=call+sql+server+stored+procedure+from+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling MySQL Stored Procedure on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005988/calling-mysql-stored-procedure-on-php)

Comment: Yes @ficuscr I have edited by question with what I tried...

Comment: Does that support `:namedParaeters`? Or do you need to use `?` ? Even if it did would assume the array key would be `'token' =>` and not `':token' =>`. Error is telling you something.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute it in this way

```
public function test(){

  $token = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
  $user =DB::select('EXEC export.spGetConnection ?', [$token]);
  print_r(json_encode($user));
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: I have tested this but still giving error: i.e. "_SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'spGetConnection' expects parameter '@ReturnJSON', which was not supplied. (SQL: EXEC export.spGetConnection 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)_"